# java 8 nashorn engine is really slow

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I am running the following javascript test

```
var mark = java.lang.System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
for(var i = 0; i != 1000; i++) {
}
var now = java.lang.System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
var e = now - mark;
print(1 / e);
```

and get this result

```
27.361456496425802
```

this seems really slow almost a bug or something i am doing wrong. Here is the java code

```
    try {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");

        String[] lines = IO.readAllLines(IO.file(root, "LoadList.txt"));

        String script = "";

        for(int i = 0; i != lines.length; i++) {
            String file = lines[i].trim();

            if(!file.startsWith("#") && file.length() != 0) {
                script += IO.readAllText(IO.file(root, file));
            }
        }

        engine.eval(script);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

does anybody know what i am doing wrong or have seen this type of problem and know how to fix if?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you printing `1/e` rather than `e`?

Comment: You print `1/e` with `e`the time diff. `e` is about 36.5ms

Comment: 1/e (e is in seconds) gives me frames per second like the loop was running in a game update iteration. I just get a better understanding of the speed that way. But it still seems really slow i am not sure how fast javascript generally runs but i was hoping for at least say 1000 frames per second or even a couple 10s of thousands of frames per second would be nice. A loop 1000 times would be common in a game update for instance running a particle system

Comment: To explain a little further. If the empty loop is only running at around 27 frames per second a game implementing a particle system in it's update iteration would have no hope of going above 27 frames per second with this implementation and probably much less because of the instructions that have to be put in the empty loop to implement the particle system

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research it appears that java's javascript takes a little while to warm up to speed. here is an update to the test

```
for(var i = 0; i != 1000; i++) {
  var mark = java.lang.System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
  for(var j = 0; j != 1000; j++) {
  }
  var now = java.lang.System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
  var e = now - mark;
  print(1 / e + " fps")
}
```

and by the last iteration i get 99108.03064699778 fps. (it does vary the lowest one i got, on the last iteration, was around 50000 fps)